# C# Foreach item in CheckedListBox only gets one item

Tags: c#, database, foreach

When I check more than one item in the `CheckedListBox`, than it only gets the `Selected.Value` of the last selected item and uses that for the amount of times the foreach is used.

Extra context: It's an application that can put exercises on certain days, so it's a workout app, but when you select more than 1 exercise in the `CheckedListBox`, than it only adds items with the last selected value.

So *selects 3 different items(pushups, pullups, situps)* --> *3 situps get added with all the same values*.

Code that adds exercises to the other **normal** `ListBox`:

```
        query = "INSERT INTO Xercise_Day (DayId, ExerciseId) " +
               "VALUES(@DayId, @ExerciseId)";

        foreach (CheckedListBox exercise in clbXcercises.CheckedItems)
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DayId", scrollBarDays.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExerciseId", clbXcercises.SelectedValue);

                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);

                lsBoxDailyX.DataSource = data;
                lsBoxDailyX.DisplayMember = "Naam";              
            }

            DailyX();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < clbXcercises.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            clbXcercises.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
```

Comment: You're not using the properties of the `exercise` object that you get in the `foreach`.  Where you add the command parameter you need to use `exercise.Value`.

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExerciseId", clbXcercises.SelectedValue); become command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExerciseId", exercise.SelectedValue);

Comment: I would suggest not opening your database for each and every update, open, do updates, close.

Comment: @JoeTaras It gives an error saying  'object' does not contain definition for 'SelectedValue' and no accessible extension method etc etc etc

Comment: @Archer value doesn't exist in that context

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai: Dear, you must cast your exercise object, so you can get its property

Comment: @JoeTaras sorry I'm pretty bad at c# and fairly new. How do I cast it?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai: clbXcercises.GetItemCheckState(clbXcercises.Items.IndexOf(exercise))

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @JoeTaras Doesn't that give the index? Instead of the value that was given to it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, reference `exercise` instead of `clbXcercises` to get the selected value. The code becomes:

```
foreach (object exercise in clbXcercises.CheckedItems)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DayId", scrollBarDays.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExerciseId", exercise.ToString());

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(data);

        lsBoxDailyX.DataSource = data;
        lsBoxDailyX.DisplayMember = "Naam";              
    }

    DailyX();
}
```

Comment: I get the error: " 'object' does not contain definition for 'SelectedValue' and no accessible extension method etc etc etc "

Comment: But it needs an integer returned, not a string